# Bulma table issue - cell collapsing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bulma

I'm having an issue using Bulma. I've installed a bulma-rails gem in my Rails application. The table cell is collapsing.
I am failing to have a fixed th tag "Date of Birth". "Date of birth" is cut in 3 lines. See image

[image]

I've tried to set some css classes but nothing. The only way is to have th tag with just one word of a longer text. See example below

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` css rule to `<td>` or `<th>`.